# My caramels sugared but I don't want to throw them away. Is there any way I can reheat the sugared mess and turn it into a caramel sauce?

Tags: caramel

My caramels sugared but I don't want to throw them away. Is there any way I can reheat the sugared mess and turn it into a caramel sauce? I am determined not to waste this great taste but want to lose the lousy texture.

Comment: Can you edit your post and include the recipe/method you followed?

Comment: Do you mean that they crystallized?

Answer (score 2):

Worry not, you can fix this: The sugar crystals that formed in your caramel behave just like ordinary sugar crystals - they dissolve in water or other liquids.

This means you can still turn your caramels into a caramel sauce, drizzle or spread.

You don't give an amount, so no recipe, but gently heat the caramels with some cream in a pot. You may also want to add a knob or two of butter. Cook until the sugar is dissolved and you get a not-too-thin sauce, pour into jars and refrigerate. If it solidifies in the fridge, gently warm in the microwave until spreadable/pourable before using. The consistency will depend on how much cream and/or butter you add, obviously.

There is a great [Serious Eats article on caramel sauce](http://www.seriouseats.com/2016/09/how-to-make-a-basic-easy-caramel-sauce.html), which you might want to use as a base when calculating how much butter and cream you shoukd add.