# Caramel fudge pieces into sauce?

Tags: sauce, sugar, dessert, caramel, fudge

I'm wondering if there is a way to turn store-bought caramel fudge pieces into a caramel sauce?  Would that be possible?

Comment: possibly related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/86471/69382

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fudge is a mixture of sugar, butter and milk/cream, made by slowly crystallising sugar at about 115C. You can make a caramel sauce by heating sugar and water to this temperature, and then adding cream (or maybe evaporated milk), followed by more gentle heating. So I think there is a chance it will work. You might want to add some extra cream for richness and texture.